# I made a hamburger menu button but it only toggles the first element

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, dom-events, hamburger-menu

So I made my little hamburger icon, I made my toggle JS function but it seems to toggle only the first element of the list. This is my HTML header and the button of the hamburger menu:

```
<button onclick='hideBlock()' class="hamburger">
        <span>&mdash;</span>
        <span>&mdash;</span>
        <span>&mdash;</span>
</button>

<header>
        <nav>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- <img src="resurse/img/logo.png" alt="logo-alb" class="logo"> -->
                <ul class="main-nav">
                    <li class="e-nav"><a href="#descriere">Descriere magazin</a></li>
                    <li class="e-nav"><a href="#functioneaza">Cum functioneaza ?</a></li>
                    <li class="e-nav"><a href="#adresa">Adresa</a></li>
                    <li class="e-nav"><a href="#recenzii">Recenzii</a></li>
                    <li class="e-nav"><a href="#promotii">Promotii</a></li>
                    <li class="e-nav"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="hero-text-box">
            <h1>Cel mai bun magazin. <br> Cele mai bune preturi.</h1>
            <a href="#adresa" class="btn btn-full">Vreau sa cumpar</a>
            <a href="#promotii" class="btn btn-ghost">Arata-mi mai mult</a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

This is the JS function I tried:

```
function hideBlock() {
    x = document.querySelector('.main-nav .e-nav');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none'
    }
}
```

Also, this is the CSS for the query I'm trying to implement this in:

```
 .main-nav .e-nav{
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
        font-size: 120%;
    }
```

I am not quite sure what the solution might be, any sort of help would be greatly aprreciated

Comment: `document.querySelector()` only returns the first match. Even if it didn't, you'd have to iterate over the resulting NodeList.

Comment: Hmm, which then would be a better option. Should I use getElementsByName ?

Comment: No, and you don't need that class eitther: `document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav li")`

Comment: Do you need you entire list item should be visible on click of button?

Comment: @Vijay yeah, that's what I want. I want it to toggle between 'none' and 'block' at the click of the button

Comment: @ChrisG I used querySelectorAll('.main-nav li') instead and I also changed the CSS with '.main-nav li' instead of '.main-nav .e-nav' but now it seems that my console reports an error whenever I try clicking the button, which states: "Cannot read property 'display' of undefined", the line it refers to is this one: 'if (x.style.display === 'none') {'

Comment: Yeah, like I said in my first comment, the result of that function is a list of nodes and thus doesn't have a `.style` property. Always check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: @ChrisG Yup, I managed to solve it in the end, thanks for the help, hope you have a great day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a fix for this later on. I tried altering my code basted on a suggestion from a person in the comments `document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav li")` but that throwed an error in my console, which stated `Cannot read property 'display' of undefined`. That's because the querySelectorAll returns a nodeList. So to solve that, I had to iterate through every single node, since I wanted all items to get shown and hidden at the press of the button. So I looped my code as it follows:

```
function hideBlock() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll('.main-nav li');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].style.display === 'none') {
            x[i].style.display = 'block'
        } else {
            x[i].style.display = 'none'
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks to everyone who tried helping me, hope you have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of display:none to each list item you hide the hole list(ul) itself.And then toggle it using js.

```
.main-nav {
        display: none;
    }

    .main-nav .e-nav {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
        font-size: 120%;
    }
<button onclick='hideBlock()' class="hamburger">
    <span>&mdash;</span>
    <span>&mdash;</span>
    <span>&mdash;</span>
</button>

<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- <img src="resurse/img/logo.png" alt="logo-alb" class="logo"> -->
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li class="e-nav"><a href="#descriere">Descriere magazin</a></li>
                <li class="e-nav"><a href="#functioneaza">Cum functioneaza ?</a></li>
                <li class="e-nav"><a href="#adresa">Adresa</a></li>
                <li class="e-nav"><a href="#recenzii">Recenzii</a></li>
                <li class="e-nav"><a href="#promotii">Promotii</a></li>
                <li class="e-nav"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="hero-text-box">
        <h1>Cel mai bun magazin. <br> Cele mai bune preturi.</h1>
        <a href="#adresa" class="btn btn-full">Vreau sa cumpar</a>
        <a href="#promotii" class="btn btn-ghost">Arata-mi mai mult</a>
    </div>
</header>

function hideBlock(){
    x = document.querySelector('.main-nav');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
 }
```